I can't install Ubuntu operating system on my computer, error as shown in the image below, please help
laptop dell latitude e7240.

Initramfs unpacking failed: invalid magic at start of compressed archive

Did you validate the ISO? (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0) as that error can occur when the image is invalid (including user error such as incorrect architecture for your device was downloaded). Did you verify ISO write to your media?  You provide release (24.10) but not which product & what if any checks/documentation on install you followed.

This question is similar to: Booting 24.04 from USB with UEFI fails with: "Initramfs unpacking failed" and "Kernel panic". If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

WIndows used for creating the media => ALWAYS right click and Eject the media. This is the same as "unmount" under Linux, always do it before removing media.
